# How to remove unread count from Gmail tab in web browser?

Tags: gmail

How do I remove the unread count from the Gmail tab in my web browser?

According to my web searches, there was a Gmail Labs feature that supported this around 2012, but it's long gone.

I want to remove the unread count because it's distracting: when I see a non-zero number there I tend to click on the Gmail tab impulsively.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround for Firefox and Chrome: if you "pin" the Gmail tab, by right clicking on the tab and choosing "pin tab", then the tab shrinks and only the Gmail icon remains visible.

This has the added benefit of clearing up space in your tab bar.

Comment: They now have an emoticon with the number of emails baked in. Grr.